# How do to put together data on the same information?

Tags: r

This my data:

[image]

I want to put together data on the same week.

The variable must list.

example:

```
[[1]]
[1]   date     point
    2016/1/1    123
    2016/1/2     60
    2016/1/3     98

[[2]]
[1]   date     point
    2016/1/4     33
    2016/1/5     56
    2016/1/6    150
    2016/1/7     39
    2016/1/8    111
    2016/1/9     78
    2016/1/10   113
[[3]]
[1]
    ..........
[[4]]
[1]
    ..........
```

How can I do?

Comment: `split(df, df$week)` - this must be a duplicate. I'll see if I can find one.

Comment: @thelatemail Yeah. Your answer is my mean.